# Concatenating all Possible Column Values of Other Unique Column

Tags: python, pandas

**Problem Setting**

Suppose I am given the following data frame.

```
ID    category
223    MMO
223    Game
444    Finance
360    Reading
360    Book
```

This data frame has an `ID` column and it's associated `category`. Notice that the same `ID` can have multiple categories.

My goal is to create a new column, which contains the concatenation of all the possible categories for a given `ID`. This means:

- Removing the old `category` column
- Removing duplicate `ID` rows

The output would look like this.

```
ID    category 
223    MMO_Game      
444    Finance    
360    Reading_Book
```

**Attempted Solution**

My though process was to first create a groupby variable that would group `category` by `ID`.

```
groupby_ID = df['category'].groupby(df['ID'])
```

Now I can try and iterate through the grouped data and concatenate the strings.

```
for ID, category in groupby_appID:
```

I don't know how to go on at this point. Some pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `groupby` on ID and then apply a `join` with your desired separator:

```
In [142]:
df.groupby('ID')['category'].apply('_'.join)

Out[142]:
ID
223        MMO_Game
360    Reading_Book
444         Finance
Name: category, dtype: object
```

To get the exact desired output you can call `reset_index` with `name` param:

```
In [145]:
df.groupby('ID')['category'].apply('_'.join).reset_index(name='category')

Out[145]:
    ID      category
0  223      MMO_Game
1  360  Reading_Book
2  444       Finance
```

Comment: Genius @EdChum! I think I overthought the problem, no need for loops.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious you can do this, it's tempting to start using `lambda`s or some kind of built in method but it's a nice compact way of achieving what you want

Comment: I saw @EdChum had answered and I didn't want his answer to influence mine.  So I didn't look.  I came up with functionally the same solution but this is more elegant.    `df.groupby('ID').category.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x))`.  Great answer @EdChum.